# reverse multimap in java

Tags: java, multimap

I have a multimap and I iterate it with `hasnext()`.

```
Set keySet = myMap.keySet();    

Iterator keyIterator = keySet.iterator();    

while (keyIterator.hasNext() ) {    

    Integer key = (Integer) keyIterator.next();    

    System.out.println("K"+key);    

    List values = (List) myMap.get(key);    

    System.out.println("V"+values);    

}
```

And the output is :

K=4,

V=[Sam India],

K=3,

V=[Sam, Sam US],

K=5,

V=[Sam]

But I need the output in the reverse format like :

K=5,

V=[Sam],

K=3,

V=[Sam, Sam US],

K=4,

V=[Sam India]

Can we have hasPrevious() in multimap?

Answer (score 1):

You really should start using generics.

The simplest hack probably is to use

```
ArrayList<List<?>> list = new ArrayList<>(keySet);
ListIterator<List<?>> iter = list.listIterator(list.size() - 1);
```

and then iterate backwards. However, this will serialize the set, so it's `O(n)` extra memory.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to take the size of the map, and retrieve records in the reverse order, starting from the last index. Do you want to use Iterator only? Or you can write your custom Iterator to get the desired functionality.

Comment: Try this - for(int i=myMap.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {}

Comment: Are you sure the [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface provides an index access ? I don't think :/